# java: work with stdin/stdout of process in same time

Tags: java

I have running process in thread (RunFile) and i have 2 threads for work with his stdin and stdout (WriteStdin, ReadStdout). When process writes only to stdout and not working with stdin, all is right. 
When process write anything to stdout and waiting for input from stdin, ReadStdout not write anything, until WriteStdin not send variable to the process. When is process exited, then ReadStdout prints all. In this case i need to ReadStdout made ​​the first listing and then the process waiting for input from stdin.

This class creates a Thread that is running the process and also creates threads ReadStdout and WriteStdin.

```
package bin;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class RunFile implements Runnable{

    public Thread program = null;
    public Process process = null;

    private JTextArea console; 

    public RunFile(JTextArea cons){ 
        console = cons;

        program = new Thread(this);
        program.start();
    }

    public void run() {     
        try {   
            String exe = "path to executable file";

            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exe);

            ReadStdout read = new ReadStdout(process); 
            WriteStdin write = new WriteStdin(process, console);

            process.waitFor();  

            write.write.stop();
            read.read.stop();

            System.out.println("\nExit value: " + process.exitValue() + "\n");  
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
        catch (IOException e1) {}       
    }
}
```

This class create a thread, which work with stdin of process.
Thread is permanently suspended, is triggered only when the moment has something to write to stdin

```
package bin;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

class WriteStdin implements Runnable{

    private Process process = null;
    private JTextArea console = null;
    public Thread write = null;
    private String input = null;
    private BufferedWriter writer = null;

    public WriteStdin(Process p, JTextArea t){

        process = p;
        console = t;
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

        write = new Thread(this);
        write.start();

        console.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e){

                //save the last lines for console to variable input
                if(e.getKeyChar() == '\n'){

                    try {                       
                        int line = console.getLineCount() -2;
                        int start = console.getLineStartOffset(line);
                        int end = console.getLineEndOffset(line);

                        input = console.getText(start, end  - start);

                        write.resume();

                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {}
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void run(){
        write.suspend();
        while(true){
            try {
                //send variable input in stdin of process
                writer.write(input);
                writer.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {}
            write.suspend();
        }
    }
}
```

This class create a thread, which work with stdout of process

```
package bin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

class ReadStdout implements Runnable{

    public Thread read = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
    private Process process = null;

    public ReadStdout(Process p){

        process = p;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        read = new Thread(this);
        read.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
        try {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if(line != null)
                    System.out.println (line);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        }       
    }
}
```

This is an example source (in C) of programs that i use when creating process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%d\n", i);

  char a[10];
  scanf("%s", a);
  printf("%s\n",a);

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%d\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a *lot* of code to have to wade through.  Narrow it down to the smallest portion that can help folks understand your issue.

Comment: I would strongly advise not using `thread.stop()`, but instead to simply tell your runnable not to run anymore (consider a `boolean running` member variable.)

Comment: +1 for `thread.stop` caveat.  For anyone who hasn't read it, the javadoc says "Deprecated. This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior."

Comment: thanks for the comments on thread.stop (), however it does not solve my problem. problem remains even when not use thread from WriteStdin, the process stops at the request of input from stdin and ReadStdout nothing prints. I think the problem is with the process but i do not know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, in Linux  the process must create this:

```
String exe = "absolute path to executable file";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command().add("bash");
builder.command().add("-c");
builder.command().add("stdbuf -o0 " + exe);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
```

Stdout is not buffered and my program works.