# Web Services developed using netbeans - how to return objects of java classes in a web service program

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, apache-axis

I've developed a Axis2 web service using Netbeans IDE for Java. I want to return an object of type `java.lang.Process` class from the web service program. I have deployed it in the GlassFish server successfully but when I try to consume the web service by writing a client, the return type is shown as Object. How do I capture the exact type returned from the web service?

```
public Process comp(String filename, String filecontent) {
   Process p = null;
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   String msg = "";
   String command[] = new String[4];
   command[0] = "cmd";
   command[1] = "/C";
   command[2] = "javac";
   command[3] = filename;
   String envp[] = new String[1];
   envp[0] = "path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin";
   File dir = new File("Path to file");
   try {
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(jfile);
      writer.append(filecontent);
      writer.close();
      p = rt.exec(command, envp, dir);
      return p;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      //
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, for first of all, trying to return a Process object in a web service is less than useful, can't really imagine why you would want to do this. Second, since the only way to do this is by running java2wsdl, please post ***relevant*** portions of your Java class and the generated WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please refer to my earlier question at the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677455/implementation-of-simple-java-ide-using-runtime-process-and-jtextarea. I've solved that issue using multithreading concept. As the users programs are compiled and executed remotely, I need to write a web service to do this task. The result of which is sent back to the user on the output window. But the code to set custom IO console include multithreading concepts. Can I include those classes inside a web service?

Comment: Otherwise I want to return the Process object which invokes the compilers in the remote machine to execute the given program so that I can catch Process object returned and capture the IO streams of Process object to read interactive input from the user via the output window. That is the idea. So help me how to return Process object from a web service and in particular how to run java2wsdl in netbeans? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't put (multi-line) code in comments, it just doesn't format in a way that anyone will want to read it. Like I said before, you cannot send a `Process` object over the wire to your clients to do anything useful with. Given the requirements you have described I think you need to redesign your solution.