# jTextArea as IO console

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How do I send the input of the user, user input only, to the outputstream?

I'm currently using a keylistner,

```
jTextArea console = new jTextArea;
console.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e){
            //save the last lines for console to variable input
            if(e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){

                try {
                    int line = console.getLineCount() -2;
                    int start = console.getLineStartOffset(line);
                    int end = console.getLineEndOffset(line);
                    input = console.getText(start, end  - start);
                    send = true;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });`
```

As you can see, when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the entire last line of the console, textarea.

What I want to happen is, send only the user inputs, not the entire last line.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What else is inputting into your text area?

Comment: The inputstream, STDOUT. The jTextArea is used as if a console for IO.

Comment: You COULD use your key listener to mark that point that the user started typing and reset it when the press enter and only send the characters between those two points.  I'd prefer to keep track of what was last written by the `STDOUT` personally...

Comment: Yes, this what I was thinking just earlier, but I have no idea on how I could implement this..

Comment: ...Which one?  The `KeyListener` or the `STDOUT` monitor...?

Comment: Actually both, I tried using `KeyListener` but I didn't go far. `STDOUT` in the other hand, it is printed on a different class, that's why I haven't tried it. My code is actually based from this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677455/implementation-of-simple-java-ide-using-runtime-process-and-jtextarea)

Comment: So, from the sounds of it, you need a single point of entry.  Somewhere you can say `write(String)` that will return back the start and end positions of the text.  This way you could (technically) maintain a (short) list of recent entries....

Comment: I don't actually get you, but let me tell you how I'm trying to implement the `KeyListener`
I have an else statement on the keyReleased method which goes,
`}else{
                    if(startflag){
                        start = console.getCaretPosition();
                        startflag = false;
                    }
                }`

then `startflag = true;` on the if statement.

Comment: You might 'cheat' and have the input in a `JTextField` and the output in a `JTextArea`.  Add an `ActionListener` to the text field and when the user presses enter, write it to the text area as though it had been put there by the user.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have thought of this, but I wanted to have just 1 component for this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so this is my idea...

The basic idea is we want to keep track of "user" input and "process" output.

Basically what I've done is set it up so that when the process terminates, we calculate the current position of the caret in the document and mark that as the start position of the user input.

This example doesn't include writing output to the process, you can slide that in ;)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException;

public class QuickTerminal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuickTerminal();
    }

    public QuickTerminal() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ConsolePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public interface CommandListener {

        public void commandOutput(String text);

        public void commandCompleted(String cmd, int result);

        public void commandFailed(Exception exp);

    }

    public class ConsolePane extends JPanel implements CommandListener {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        private int userInputStart = 0;
        private Command cmd;

        public ConsolePane() {

            cmd = new Command(this);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            textArea = new JTextArea(20, 30);
            add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

            textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        int range = textArea.getCaretPosition() - userInputStart;
                        try {
                            String text = textArea.getText(userInputStart, range).trim();
                            System.out.println("[" + text + "]");
                            userInputStart += range;
                            if (!cmd.isRunning()) {
                                cmd.execute(text);
                            } else {
                            }
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(QuickTerminal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } else {
//                        if (!cmd.isRunning()) {
//                            cmd.send(...);
//                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void commandOutput(String text) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AppendTask(textArea, text));
        }

        @Override
        public void commandFailed(Exception exp) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AppendTask(textArea, "Command failed - " + exp.getMessage()));
        }

        @Override
        public void commandCompleted(String cmd, int result) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int pos = textArea.getCaretPosition();

                    System.out.println("pos = " + pos + "; length = " + textArea.getText().length());

                    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length());
                    userInputStart = pos;
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class AppendTask implements Runnable {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        private String text;

        public AppendTask(JTextArea textArea, String text) {
            this.textArea = textArea;
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            textArea.append(text);
        }

    }

    public class Command {

        private CommandListener listener;

        private ProcessRunner runner;

        public Command(CommandListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {

            return runner != null && runner.isAlive();

        }

        public void execute(String cmd) {

            if (!cmd.trim().isEmpty()) {


                List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(25);
                if (cmd.contains("\"")) {

                    while (cmd.contains("\"")) {

                        String start = cmd.substring(0, cmd.indexOf("\""));
                        cmd = cmd.substring(start.length());
                        String quote = cmd.substring(cmd.indexOf("\"") + 1);
                        cmd = cmd.substring(cmd.indexOf("\"") + 1);
                        quote = quote.substring(0, cmd.indexOf("\""));
                        cmd = cmd.substring(cmd.indexOf("\"") + 1);

                        if (!start.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            String parts[] = start.trim().split(" ");
                            values.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                        }
                        values.add(quote.trim());

                    }

                    if (!cmd.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        String parts[] = cmd.trim().split(" ");
                        values.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                    }

                    for (String value : values) {
                        System.out.println("[" + value + "]");
                    }

                } else {

                    if (!cmd.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        String parts[] = cmd.trim().split(" ");
                        values.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                    }

                }

                runner = new ProcessRunner(listener, values);

            }

        }

        public void send(String cmd) {
            // Send user input to the running process...
        }

    }

    public class ProcessRunner extends Thread {

        private List<String> cmds;
        private CommandListener listener;

        public ProcessRunner(CommandListener listener, List<String> cmds) {
            this.cmds = cmds;
            this.listener = listener;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("cmds = " + cmds);
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
                pb.redirectErrorStream();
                Process p = pb.start();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(listener, p.getInputStream());
                // Need a stream writer...

                int result = p.waitFor();

                // Terminate the stream writer
                reader.join();

                listener.commandCompleted(null, result);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public class StreamReader extends Thread {

        private InputStream is;
        private CommandListener listener;

        public StreamReader(CommandListener listener, InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
            this.listener = listener;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int value = -1;
                while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                    listener.commandOutput(Character.toString((char) value));
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

PS- I was running this on my Mac, so you might need to put in a call to "cmd" for Windows... ;)

PPS- This is an incomplete example, if it wasn't 1am I might fill it in, but, this doesn't stop the user from pressing back space beyond the last known user input position. If I was going to fix this, I would use a `DocumentFilter` and simply "protect" all the text before the user position, disallowing the user from removing it

**Updated with "Protected DocumentFilter" example**

Added a "protected" `DocumentFilter` to protected areas of the `Document` that the user should no longer be allowed to edit.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class QuickTerminal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuickTerminal();
    }

    public QuickTerminal() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ConsolePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface CommandListener {

        public void commandOutput(String text);

        public void commandCompleted(String cmd, int result);

        public void commandFailed(Exception exp);
    }

    public class ConsolePane extends JPanel implements CommandListener, UserInput {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        private int userInputStart = 0;
        private Command cmd;

        public ConsolePane() {

            cmd = new Command(this);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            textArea = new JTextArea(20, 30);
            ((AbstractDocument)textArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new ProtectedDocumentFilter(this));
            add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

            textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        int range = textArea.getCaretPosition() - userInputStart;
                        try {
                            String text = textArea.getText(userInputStart, range).trim();
                            System.out.println("[" + text + "]");
                            userInputStart += range;
                            if (!cmd.isRunning()) {
                                cmd.execute(text);
                            } else {
                            }
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(QuickTerminal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } else {
//                        if (!cmd.isRunning()) {
//                            cmd.send(...);
//                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void commandOutput(String text) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AppendTask(textArea, text));
        }

        @Override
        public void commandFailed(Exception exp) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AppendTask(textArea, "Command failed - " + exp.getMessage()));
        }

        @Override
        public void commandCompleted(String cmd, int result) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int pos = textArea.getCaretPosition();

                    System.out.println("pos = " + pos + "; length = " + textArea.getText().length());

                    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length());
                    userInputStart = pos;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getUserInputStart() {
            return userInputStart;
        }
    }

    public interface UserInput {

        public int getUserInputStart();
    }

    public class AppendTask implements Runnable {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        private String text;

        public AppendTask(JTextArea textArea, String text) {
            this.textArea = textArea;
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            textArea.append(text);
        }
    }

    public class Command {

        private CommandListener listener;
        private ProcessRunner runner;

        public Command(CommandListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {

            return runner != null && runner.isAlive();

        }

        public void execute(String cmd) {

            if (!cmd.trim().isEmpty()) {


                List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(25);
                if (cmd.contains("\"")) {

                    while (cmd.contains("\"")) {

                        String start = cmd.substring(0, cmd.indexOf("\""));
                        cmd = cmd.substring(start.length());
                        String quote = cmd.substring(cmd.indexOf("\"") + 1);
                        cmd = cmd.substring(cmd.indexOf("\"") + 1);
                        quote = quote.substring(0, cmd.indexOf("\""));
                        cmd = cmd.substring(cmd.indexOf("\"") + 1);

                        if (!start.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            String parts[] = start.trim().split(" ");
                            values.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                        }
                        values.add(quote.trim());

                    }

                    if (!cmd.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        String parts[] = cmd.trim().split(" ");
                        values.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                    }

                    for (String value : values) {
                        System.out.println("[" + value + "]");
                    }

                } else {

                    if (!cmd.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        String parts[] = cmd.trim().split(" ");
                        values.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                    }

                }

                runner = new ProcessRunner(listener, values);

            }

        }

        public void send(String cmd) {
            // Send user input to the running process...
        }
    }

    public class ProcessRunner extends Thread {

        private List<String> cmds;
        private CommandListener listener;

        public ProcessRunner(CommandListener listener, List<String> cmds) {
            this.cmds = cmds;
            this.listener = listener;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("cmds = " + cmds);
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
                pb.redirectErrorStream();
                Process p = pb.start();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(listener, p.getInputStream());
                // Need a stream writer...

                int result = p.waitFor();

                // Terminate the stream writer
                reader.join();

                listener.commandCompleted(null, result);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class StreamReader extends Thread {

        private InputStream is;
        private CommandListener listener;

        public StreamReader(CommandListener listener, InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
            this.listener = listener;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int value = -1;
                while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                    listener.commandOutput(Character.toString((char) value));
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ProtectedDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private UserInput userInput;

        public ProtectedDocumentFilter(UserInput userInput) {
            this.userInput = userInput;
        }

        public UserInput getUserInput() {
            return userInput;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (offset >= getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            if (offset >= getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                super.remove(fb, offset, length); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if (offset >= getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not replying for a long time. Anyway, I got it working now, using keyListners and startflags. I'm getting  `javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Length must be positive` exception when I renew the console constructor. Does `consoleConstructorMethod = null` nullifies the existing constructor?
My code goes like this.

`consoleConstructorMethod = null;
new consoleConstructorMethod;`

I think I get this exception because of that, the console is being renewed.

Comment: To be honest, it's hard to know without seeing the actual code.  Best to post a new question

Comment: Hi! Can you help me about that DocumentFilter and "protect" you're talking about? An idea would be helpful.. Thank you..

Comment: I've added a new example using `DocumentFilter` to protect areas beyond the current user input range - only done quick testing, but the idea should be sound

Comment: @useletters I should also mention, I got this example to work on windows by using "cmd /c ..." to do things like directory listings ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that when any other key is released, if starflag = true you store the start, and set startflag to false as you said, and when "enter" is actually pressed, you can do startflag = true; and store the end as the getCaretPosition().

My understanding of your intentions beyond that is slightly vague, but here are my ideas:
If you have an entire "conversation" of sorts going on in your console, and you want ALL of the user entries, then you could simply use an ArrayList userinputs, and instead of start = console.getCaretPosition(), you could do userinputs.add(new Point(console.getCaretPosition(),-1)); and then when the user ends his input(or before STDOUT sends input), do userinputs.get(userinputs.size()-1).y = console.getCaretPosition()(Or you could store a temporary point, and only add the point upon it's completion - when it get an end as well.)

If you are sending the user input to the output whenever the enter key is pressed, then I don't see what more is needed than the simple code above, that essentially works like this:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
    startflag = true;
    //Just get the text from the start(stored below), and up until where the caret is now, as the users output.
}else{
    if(startflag){
         start = console.getCaretPosition()
         startflag = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is actually my code right now. But it kind of doesn't work at some instance. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn