# Stopping a JTextPane from receiving new line feeds

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I want my `JTextPane` to have some functionality when the user presses **Enter** and not just change the line. Now I understand how to implement the functionality I want, but I still can't negate the line feed from pressing **Enter**. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work, the new line will be created anyway.

To give a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve here, the textpane is supposed to contain a certain filepath, so I want the user to be able to scroll only horizontaly and not add new lines verticaly. Is the JTextPane component suitable for this use?

```
locationPane = new JTextPane();
    locationPane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                locationPane.setText(locationPane.getText().substring(0, locationPane.getText().length()));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the textpane is supposed to contain a certain filepath, so I want the user to be able to scroll only horizontaly and not add new lines verticaly. Is the JTextPane component suitable for this use?

I would suggest there are better options.

If you only have a single line of text then just use a `JTextField`. To handle the Enter key you can add an `ActionListener` to the text field.

If you do need multiple line then I would suggest you could use a `JList`.

Answer (score 3):

`KeyListener` is never a suitable soution for text components.  Instead you should be using a `DocumentFilter` to filter out things you don't want to be added to the underlying `Document`.

See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more details

You could also alter the `insert-break` key binding, changing the behaviour or taking additional action.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778) for more details

Comment: That "DocumentFilter Examples" link points to a casino add for me, is this the case for anyone else?

Comment: @Barny Which is a shame, as they were overall good examples