# java program hangs when ProcessBuilder executes script with input prompt

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a batch and shell script that execute MYSQL command.

```
mysql -u user -p < path\etc\script\db\dosomething.sql
```

I have a java program that uses ProcessBuilder to execute the batch script.
I am aware that this command will prompt the user for the password , I am also aware that I can alternatively use the --password (which throws an unsafe warning) or a config file to set the login parameters.
I want to provide the password using the input prompt via ProcessBuilder but when I run the program it just hangs and I have no idea why.
When I use JVisualVM to view what is happening I notice that the OutputStream thread is not running and if it did then what is hanging the program ? Below is my implementation:-

Class that deals with the InputStream and ErrorStream :

```
public static class InStream extends Thread {

    private final InputStream in;
    private final PrintWriter pw;

    public InStream(InputStream in, PrintWriter pw, String threadName) {
        super(threadName);
        this.in = in;
        this.pw = pw;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class that deals with the OutputStream:

```
public static class OutStream extends Thread {

    private final String message;
    private final OutputStream out;

    public OutStream(OutputStream out, String threadName, String message) {
        super(threadName);
        this.out = out;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);) {
            pw.println(message);
            pw.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String password = "Y0urp@ssw0rd";
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("path\\etc\\script\\cli\\batchWithSQLCommand.bat");
        Process process = builder.start();
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        StringWriter input = new StringWriter();
        new OutStream(process.getOutputStream(), "output-stream-thread", password).start();
        new InStream(process.getErrorStream(), new PrintWriter(errors, true), "error-stream-thread").start();
        new InStream(process.getInputStream(), new PrintWriter(input, true), "input-stream-thread").start();
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("inputStream: " + input.toString());
        System.out.println("Error Stream: " + errors.toString());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
       //throw error here
    } catch (Error | Exception ex) {
         //throw error here
    }
}
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: [The following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778) illustrates a means to execute an external command and write to it's `OutputStream` - kind of the important idea is to write to the `OutputStream` only when it's expected. This means you need to parse the input and when you "detect" the password prompt, then write to the password to the `OutputStream`

Comment: Interestingly enough I have used your batch file to test and see if I can capture the prompt and I am able to but when I switch back to my script the MYSQL prompt is not being captured. I wonder why that is.

Comment: It "could" be that the mysql command's output is not been piped through console's

Comment: Any ideas of how I can overcome this ? Meanwhile I'll just use the --password option due to time

Comment: Maybe have a look at one of the redirect options of `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Yeah I have been reading on them and playing around with them. If I get a solution I will post it. if you also happen to find a solution too just post