# GUI freeze when Scanner awaits user input

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I realize that you need to use the Event Dispatch Thread to avoid freezes and deadlocks, but here I am, with freezing issues. I suspect that I'm having this issue due to encapsulated EDTs.

This is the class with the main static method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WelcomeScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

/*
 * initialize variables
 */
private JButton btnSubmit;
private JTextField nameInput;
private JLabel enterName;

public WelcomeScreen() {

    /*
     * build the welcome frame with all components
     */
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(0, 0, 514, 256);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // welcome label
    JLabel label_welcome = new JLabel("<html>Welcome to <br/>Game</html>");
    label_welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label_welcome.setBounds(159, 11, 190, 32);
    getContentPane().add(label_welcome);

    // create the warrior button
    btnSubmit = new JButton("Start");
    btnSubmit.setBounds(209, 129, 89, 23);
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
    btnSubmit.setFocusable(false);
    getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);

    enterName = new JLabel("Enter Player Name:");
    enterName.setBounds(50, 60, 150, 50);
    getContentPane().add(enterName);

    nameInput = new JTextField();
    nameInput.setBounds(212, 70, 125, 25);
    getContentPane().add(nameInput);

    // set frame visible
    setVisible(true);

}

/*
 * action listener
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    if (evt.getSource().equals(btnSubmit)) {
        dispose();
        new Core();
    }

}

/*
 * <<<<<MAIN STATIC METHOD>>>>>
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // safely start the welcome frame
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new WelcomeScreen();
        }
    });

}
}
```

And this is the second class that extends JFrame. This is the GUI that freezes up. If you look under the gameEngine() method, you will notice **String input = keyboard.next();**, which is causing the freezing. If this line is commented out, the GUI will display the two strings "test1" and "test2".

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Core extends JFrame {

/*
 * initialize variables
 */
private Scanner keyboard;
private JTextArea textArea;

public Core() {

    /*
     * create the frame that displays output messages
     */
    setBounds(0, 0, 800, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 774, 349);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scroll.setBounds(0, 0, 774, 349);
    textArea.setBounds(10, 11, 443, 279);
    panel.add(scroll);

    // THIS ISN'T EVEN SHOWING UP
    appendMessage("test1");

    // set frame visible
    setVisible(true);

    // NEITHER IS THIS
    appendMessage("test2");

    /*
     * start game engine
     */
    gameEngine();

}

/*
 * start gameEngine
 */
public void gameEngine() {

    // instantiate scanner
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<THIS HERE IS CAUSING THE GUI TO FREEZE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    String input = keyboard.next();

}

// append a message to the GUI
public void appendMessage(String s) {
    textArea.append("> " + s + "\n");
}

}
```

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the reason why. Now, you need to ask "why?" are you trying to get user input from the console from within a GUI?

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @MadProgrammer Long story short, I'm working on a simple text-based game. I found it extremely difficult making a JTextField 'act' equivalent to console input. The program simply won't wait on for  JTextField input. This is why in this case, the user types commands in console, and displays messages in the GUI.

Comment: *" I cannot make a JTextField 'act' equivalent to console input*" ... [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), but I might use the text area for output and the `JTextField` for input

Comment: *"The program simply won't wait on for JTextField input"* - Yeah it will, nothing's going to happen until the presses the [Enter] key, you're not longer working in a procedural manner (like a console would), you're working in an event driven environment

Comment: @MadProgrammer So it's possible to hold the execution of the program until you've typed and entered something in the JTextField?

Comment: Not the way you're thinking about, it's possible to be "told" when something happens, to which you will need to respond, that's how GUI's work

Comment: If you want to see how seriously complex it might be to use just a `JTextArea` as the input and output, you could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017148/jtextarea-as-io-console/15025085#15025085) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778) examples. These are executing shell commands, but the basic principle would be the same ... I say, use a `JTextField` for the input instead :P

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that the Scanner is blocking the Swing event thread, preventing your GUI from painting and interacting with the user. A simple solution is to do Scanner interaction in a background thread. A better solution is to get rid of the Scanner(System.in) altogether and get all user interaction through the GUI. Console I/O and GUI I/O should not be mixed.

A simple example of using a JTextField and layout managers to get and respond to input:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Fu22GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 50;
    private static final int ROWS = 25;
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private JTextField entryField = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);
    private String playerName;

    public Fu22GamePanel(String name) {
        this.playerName = name;
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        EntryAction entryAction = new EntryAction("Submit", KeyEvent.VK_S);
        entryField.setAction(entryAction);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(entryField);
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(entryAction));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(scrollPane);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class EntryAction extends AbstractAction {
        public EntryAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = entryField.getText();
            entryField.setText("");
            textArea.append("> " + text + "\n");
            entryField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    private static class WelcomePanel extends JPanel {
        private JTextField playerNameField = new JTextField(10);

        public WelcomePanel() {
            int wpGap = 20;
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(wpGap, wpGap, wpGap, wpGap));
            add(new JLabel("Enter Player Name:"));
            add(playerNameField);
        }

        public String getPlayerName() {
            return playerNameField.getText();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        WelcomePanel welcomePanel = new WelcomePanel();
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, welcomePanel, "Welcome to the Game", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (response != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            return;
        }

        String name = welcomePanel.getPlayerName();

        Fu22GamePanel mainPanel = new Fu22GamePanel(name);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game -- Player: " + name);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting to move the Scanner to a separate thread. Can I move the whole GUI to a separate thread instead?

Comment: @LawrenceLelo: please re-read the answer -- I'm suggesting **not** to move the scanner, I'm suggesting to **get rid of the Scanner**. You've no need for it, and it will only screw you over if you keep it.

Comment: I was referring to your 'simple solution', not the 'better solution'.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo: ignore the "simple solution" because it is simple and very very wrong.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo The "simple solution" isn't that simple, adding a thread increases the complexity of the problem by orders of magnitude, better to work with the API the way it was designed, using event handlers

Comment: @LawrenceLelo: your problem is that you need to shift your thinking from linear console programs to that of event driven GUI's. Get out of the console rut and change your thinking and the whole program will fall into place.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `JTextField` as the input, couple with an `ActionListener` to which you can respond to appropriate events, like the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Use a `JTextArea` as the output...

[image: Bad Adventure]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class NastyAdventure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NastyAdventure();
    }

    public NastyAdventure() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea output;
        private JTextField input;

        private boolean isDead = false;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            output = new JTextArea(10, 30);
            input = new JTextField(20);
            add(new JScrollPane(output));
            add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            output.setEditable(false);
            output.append("A bear appears on the trial in front of you\n");
            output.append("What do you do?");

            input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    input.setText(null);
                    if (!isDead) {
                        output.append("\nThe bear eats you, you die\n");
                        output.append("The adventure is over, the bear wins\n");
                    } else {
                        output.append("You're dead, you can't do anything\nThe adventure is over, the bear wins\n");
                    }
                    isDead = true;
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [Writing Event Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) for more details

You'll also probably want to have a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which will help you maintain the state of the game seperate from the UI

Comment: Your time is much appreciated. I have a full understanding of the concepts you demonstrated. But take this for instance; let's say the game was much more capable, as in, it allows the user to type many other different commands that trigger different things. For example, the user can type _run_ which calls a method to retreat from the bear, or the user can type _drink potion_ which calls another method to regenerate health. Now I was under the impression that the code cannot **wait** and **listen** for those commands typed in a **JTextField**.

Comment: It "depends", the code will "wait" because it's not been executed. When `actionPerformed` is called, you parse the input and decide on what should occur, so when the user types in "run" and press [Enter], the `actionPerformed` method parses the text of the `JTextField` and asks the model to perform the action. The model may update it's state which is reported back to the view and the text area updated and the cycle begins again