# JTextArea make user only be able to write on the last line in text area line CMD?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a console window GUI like the Windows CMD like. I want the user to be able to write a text command and by clicking "enter" the command will execute and the text area will go to the next line after the output, but if the user tries to write on the lines above, it will not let him write.

I am not sure if `JTextArea` is the best option for this, but I could not find anything better.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Information about swing GUI's: http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/visual/03s/lect/l7/

Comment: [That's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017148/jtextarea-as-io-console/15025085#15025085) and [that's another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778)