# (Re)Drawing text in JTextField on altered background

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, paintcomponent

I would like to give the initial text in a JTextField a different background.
Consequently I overrode paintComponent, first painted the background and then
repainted the text in front of the new background.
    Graphics.drawString method requires x/y parameters to position the string, and
the y parameter has to be adjusted according to font size. This adjustment is my
problem. I figured out a function which calculates the y value correctly for most
tested heights of Font.DIALOG, buf when applying Font.MONOSPACED the results are
different. It would, of course, be most convenient to calculate y in a way, which
works for all type faces and sizes.
    I tried to find in the sources how a JTextField is painted and climbed up till
ComponentUI, but got lost on the way.
    So any hint is welcome.
Run the code with and without specifying any command line parameter to change the font. The height flaw between inital and trailing text for DIALOG is with size 11, for MONOSPACED with size 14, 18, 20.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingTextInTf extends JFrame {
  static String[] args;

  public DrawingTextInTf() {
    setSize(250, 230);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 60, 20));
    Font font= args.length==0 ? new Font(Font.DIALOG,     Font.PLAIN, 10) :
                                new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 10);

    Box box= Box.createVerticalBox();
    for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
      JPanel p= new JPanel();
      p.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(font.getSize()+i)));
      SplitBackgroundTextField tf= new SplitBackgroundTextField();
      tf.setText("Rhinoceros");
      tf.setInitialText("Rhino");
      tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
      tf.setFont(font.deriveFont((float)font.getSize()+i));
      p.add(tf);
      box.add(p);
    }
    add(box);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String... args) {
    DrawingTextInTf.args= args;
    EventQueue.invokeLater(DrawingTextInTf::new);
  }


  class SplitBackgroundTextField extends JTextField {
    int margin= 2;
    Color inactiveBackground= UIManager.getColor("TextField.inactiveBackground");
    String initialText;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int iWidth= g.getFontMetrics(getFont()).stringWidth(initialText);
      g.setColor(inactiveBackground);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, iWidth+margin, getHeight());
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      int iFontSize= g.getFont().getSize();
//  The y-position formula works for Font.DIALOG of size 10 to 20, except 11.
//  Font.MONOSPACED is not ok for 14, 18, 20.
      g.drawString(initialText, margin, (int)(iFontSize +11. -iFontSize/2.));
    }


    public void setInitialText(String text) {
      initialText= text;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean selected text that the user can overtype in the [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)?  The setSelectionStart and setSelectionEnd methods are used to color text to prompt users.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with selected text and the user will not be able to modify the text on "coloured" background. That's why I gave it the inactiveBackground colour.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers.  For example the "margin" should be `getInsets().left`. For the "y" value you should use other FontMetrics properties like ascent, height, descent. Not sure which of the above properties should be used or the formula for using them but it should provide better results for all fonts. Instead of your current approach you may want to consider the [Protected Text Component](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/protected-text-component/).

Comment: Or maybe another approach is to use a JTextPane since you can use different attributes for each part of the text. You can then use the `NavigationFilterPrefix` class in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594112/how-to-make-the-end-of-a-jtextarea-editable/46596576#46596576 to prevent the user from changing the highlighted text.

Comment: @camickr I just tested your ProtectedTextComponent and it perfectly fits my needs. Thank you very much indeed.