# A way of setting some words of jTextArea ineditable

Tags: java, filter, jtextarea

Is there a way to filter the text of a `jTextArea` by making just some of the words ineditable? I want something like highlighting the words in this code:

```
String searchWord = "Select";
Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.cyan );
int offset = jTextArea1.getText().indexOf("Select");
int length = searchWord.length();

jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
try {
    jTextArea1.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
} catch (BadLocationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That’s a complex problem - but, basically you need to start with a DocumentFilter

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017148/jtextarea-as-io-console/15025085#15025085) demonstrates a concept of a “protected” section of text, which the user can’t delete, it’s not exactly the same but may provide you some ideas

Comment: Thank's @MadProgrammer it's helpful but I understood that the text can't be deleted but I didn't find how to do the opposite operation ? I mean how can the user delete some words ?